# Is it possible to include external libraries in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, javascript

I think I know the answer, because I tried to attach an external library like this:

```
{% set location = {'type': 'external'} %}
{{ attach_library('//example.com/example.js/v3/example.js', location) }}
```

This did not attach the desired library, am I missing something, or is this a non-starter?

Comment: I don't see the `attach_library` twig extension having a second parameter.  Look for the implementation of the twig extension above in `Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension.php` in the function `attachLibrary`.  What version of twig are you using?  I'm in Drupal 8.2.1.

Answer (score 4):

Add external files in libraries: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

See the section on "CDN / externally hosted libraries".